# How to force SQL Server 2005 objects to be recompiled NOW

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, recompile

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181647%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) running `sp_recompile` forces the object to be recompiled **the next time that it is run**

I need it to be recompiled the moment I run the sp-recompile command, mainly to check for syntax errors and existence of objects on which the stored procedure depends.

--
on sql 2008 there's sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule module...

Comment: `sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule` also exists in SQL Server 2005 BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to do this is to re-deploy the stored procedure, which would (as far as I'm aware) remove the need to recompile the procedure.

Something along these lines:

```
SET @ProcedureName = 'SampleProcedure'

CREATE TABLE #ProcedureContent (Text NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #ProcedureContent
EXEC sp_helptext @ProcedureName

DECLARE @ProcedureText NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ProcedureText = ''

SELECT @ProcedureText = @ProcedureText + [Text] FROM #ProcedureContent 

EXEC ('DROP PROCEDURE ' + @ProcedureName);
EXEC (@ProcedureText)

DROP TABLE #ProcedureContent
```

Comment: @opensas, I deliberately didn't do that here so that the core of the script would be visible without extraneous "noise", but sure, go right ahead =)